# Get the count of all customers with a "billing company" in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a website in Wordpress with Woocommerce, and for my reports, I need to know how much professionnal I have.

As Woocommerce doesn't provide this information, I need to get it myself but I can't count manually.

So I decided to use the Woocommerce Rest Api to get the information.

I try to get all customers who fill the "billing company" field.

I make my request with php curl and begin my code like that :

```
//URL
$url = '<...>/wp-json/wc/v2/customers';

//REQUEST
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  

$json = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($json);
```

I get two issues :

- Can't get ALL customers
- Can't get the "billing company" variable

Any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you dont add a custom sub-tab in WooCommerce > Reports > Customers which name will be "Professionals". In this custom tab you can easily get the customers count that have a billing company.

The code is:

```
// Add a custom sub-tab to customer tab WooCommerce reports
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_reports', 'admin_report_customer_pro_section', 10, 1 );
function admin_report_customer_pro_section( $reports ){
    $reports['customers']['reports']['customer_pro'] = array(
        'title'       => __( 'Professionals', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => '',
        'hide_title'  => true,
        'callback'    => 'content_admin_report_customer_pro',
    );
    return $reports;
}

// The content of the customer custom sub-tab
function content_admin_report_customer_pro(){
    // Get all Customers
    $customers = get_users( array( 'role' => 'customer'));
    $count = 0;

    // Iterating through each customer in the array
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        // Count professional customers that have a billing company
        if( ! empty( $customer->billing_company ) ) $count++;
    }

    // Output the count
    echo '<div style="background-color:white; padding:8px 20px;"><p>'.__( 'Number of Professionals (with a company): ', 'woocommerce' ) . '<strong style="display:inline-block;background-color:#9c5d90; padding:0 10px; color:white;">' . $count . '</strong></p></div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works… You will get this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I didn't think to make it like that, it's that's better thanks a lot for the tips ! 
Anyway, I try and it works but I have doubt about the number. I have 1084 customers, when I put your code, I see 314, and I use your code to make the inverse (I change the "!=" to "=") and I get 379. the total is not 1084 O_O

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec I try the sql request and yes, it's 314 too. I also try `SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'billing_company` to list all customers with this meta, and I got only 693 so it's the count (379+314). Did Woocommerce change his database since ? it seems this SQL request only works with new woocommerce database. 
I have 391 customers that I don't know the status :/

Comment: @Efbi I have update my answer with some new code (not a SQL query)… This time it should work as expected… Try it and let me know. Thanks … I have also tried with no success a WP_query or to filter the get_users() query too. It was making exactly the same thing than the SQL query from before…

Comment: Nice one, thanks ! I think it works, I have 313 pros and 772 others, so the total is good ?
Just for my information, the get_users() query is limited to Wordpress meta or also include woocommerce customer properties meta ? like "is_paying_customer" for example ?

Comment: @Efbi I think that `get_users()` meta query is limited to wp_usermeta table…